# How to Overlay Two Polynomial Regression Graphs on One Plot Using Python Code?

Tags: python

There are two data files with the same structure but different values.

```
data1
x = [1.02, .95, .87, .77, .67, .56, .44, .30, .16, .01]
y = [0.39, .32, .27, .22, .18, .15, .13, .12, .13, .15]
data2
X = [1.0192422635379672,
     0.9451141357214766,
     0.8684850652920945,
     0.7691184213539624,
     0.6677417885676643,
     0.5562363815504198,
     0.4360893457561779,
     0.29918291891709425,
     0.15593010960109394,
     0.005485868977957057]
Y=  [0.3887694790010229,
     0.3202436634040722,
     0.2650217154648035,
     0.21781705744862176,
     0.1794694152890866,
     0.14836889336756162,
     0.1289696542458749,
     0.11660531837493848,
     0.1300477576738212,
     0.1489301668086873]
```

Now, I can use the python command to fit two polynomial regression model (2nd order),respectively.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
my_model1=numpy.poly1d(numpy.polyfit(x, y, 2))
print(np.poly1d(my_model1))
my_model2=numpy.poly1d(numpy.polyfit(X, Y, 2))
print(np.poly1d(my_model2))
```

If I plot each plot with python, I can do it using the code below.

```
#Plot the 1st 2nd polynomial regression model.
s = np.linspace(0, 1, 1)
plt.plot(s,my_model1(s),c="r",linestyle="-")
plt.title("1st 2nd order Polynomial Regression")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.axis([0, 1, 0, 0.5])
plt.grid(True)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()

#Plot the 2nd 2nd polynomial regression model.
ss = np.linspace(0, 1, 1)
plt.plot(ss,my_model1(ss),c="r",linestyle="-")
plt.title("2nd 2nd order Polynomial Regression")
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.axis([0, 1, 0, 0.5])
plt.grid(True)
plt.scatter(X,Y)
plt.show()
```

My question is how to overlay the two graphs in one plot using python code?
Thank you!

Comment: Just drop the first `plt.show()`. Matplotlib has `hold = True` by default, so multiple `plot()` calls on the same axes will keep previous plots and add the new one.

Comment: Thank you! By the way, could you please tell me why the dots can't be linked by line?

Comment: Because that's the way `scatter` plots work. To draw a line through the points, you could use `plt.plot()` with the `marker` and `linestyle` arguments. https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html